# WCF Web services calling multiple web services asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, soap

I am facing an issue from one WCF Web Service that I have created. This web service calls multiple web services to be able to build up its response for the caller.

```
var carInformation = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetCarByCarNumberAsync(brandCode, carNumber));
var carHistory = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetCarHistoryByCarNumberAsync(brandCode, carNumber));
var carConf = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetConfByCarNumberAsync(brandCode, carNumber));
var carAdvSet = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetAdvSetyByCarNumberAsync(brandCode, carNumber));
var carComp = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetComponentsyByCarNumberAsync(brandCode, carNumber));
var carDealersComments = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetDealerCommentsByCarNumberAsync(brandCode, carNumber));
var carPromotions = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetCarPromotionsAsync(brandCode, carNumber));
var carCompetitors = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetCompetitorsAsync(brandCode, carNumber));
var carSuppliers = Task.Run(() => carProvider.GetSupplierssAsync(brandCode, carNumber));

List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
taskList.Add(carInformation);
taskList.Add(carHistory);
taskList.Add(carAdvSet);
taskList.Add(carComp);
taskList.Add(carDealersComments);
taskList.Add(carPromotions);
taskList.Add(carCompetitors);
taskList.Add(carSuppliers);

await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

According to the above code snippet, I am expecting that all calls will get executed at the same time, since these are not dependent on each other. But this is not happening, when I look into the IIS Logs (from the other web service) or even if I user Fiddler to log all this requestes, I see only 5 are executed at the same time and the other ones are getting executed between the first are waiting for a response or in other cases are after one of those async calls had finalized.

Am I missing some configuration on the IIS that my web service is hosted?
Or a setting in web config that allows more thread creation on PerCall.

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)] attribute over WCF service class would help.

Comment: Why would this help?  Remember, future readers may come across this answer from Google (or Bing or wherever) - this answer as is may be correct, but does not provide anything substantial and should be a comment.